# Checking for duplicate values in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a table with following structure.

```
`post_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`post_title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`post_desc` text NOT NULL,
`post_siteid` int(5) NOT NULL
```

Is it possible to write a query in either MySQL or PHP to check for each value stored in `post_desc` which is of type text against all other values stored in the same `post_desc` field and return if it is duplicated and also return how much percent text was duplicated and the row it was duplicated with?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "*return how much percent text was duplicated*"?  Perhaps an example would help to clarify.

Comment: Two separate questions here...are you looking for duplicate text (text is exactly the same) or are you looking for post_desc that is like other post_descs?

Comment: @eggyal For example, if the contents of the first row in the `post_desc` field are "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry." If this same text is repeated in some other row, the query should return 100% if it is duplicated exactly. The query should return 75% if it is duplicated partially.... and so on.
The percentage is not important. Even if the query returns the rows where the text is duplicated, it should be enough.

Comment: @Twelfth i am looking to compare each row in post_desc with all other post_desc's and return duplicates if any.

Comment: I'm not sure what it means for the text to be "*duplicated partially*". Suppose another row contained "Foo and bar are often used as dummy variable names." Is that a partial duplicate of your Lorem Ipsum example, since they both contain the word "dummy"? If so, how should the partial match be quantified? What about a row containing "This is dumb.", which shares both the word "is" *and* the word stem "dum-" with the Lorem Ipsum example (yet shares no semantic relation)? Or "I need placeholder copy to typeset and print." which shares two common word stems and is closely related semantically?

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @a = 'hello';
SET @b = 'hell';

SELECT ((LENGTH(@a)-LENGTH(REPLACE(@a,@b,'')))/LENGTH(@a))*100 x;
+---------+
| x       |
+---------+
| 80.0000 |
+---------+
```